# Passing parameters in nginx load balancing

Tags: nginx

So I basically followed this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-nginx-load-balancing) and set up a load balancer on my nginx server.

```
upstream backend  {
  server backend1.example.com;
  server backend2.example.com;
}
```

Now all the incoming request gets distributed amongst these servers.

My question is that how can I configure nginx to something like, any request that comes to
`192.35.111.XX/?a=100` gets redirected to `backend1.example.com/?a=100` (or backend2.example.com/?a=100)

Right not `192.35.111.XX/?a=100` redirects to `backend1.example.com` (or `backend2.example.com`)

How can I configure nginx to save parameters while load balancing ?

Answer (score 0):

If you followed the steps of the tutorial, nginx does that by default and pass the original, untouched request URI to the backend.

How does the block containing the [`proxy_pass`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) directive looks like? Is there anything which, according to its documentation, might overwrite the URI passed to the backend?